# Probability of crossing between a line on a circle and a line segment inside the circle

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

Say that we have a circle centered in $(0,0)$ with a radius $R$. Inside the circle, we have a vertical line segment of length $2d$ in the center of the circle ($x_1=-d,x_2=d,y_1=y_2=0$). Now let's take two points on the circumference of the circle with angle $\theta_1,\theta_2$ and draw a line between them. You can see it better by the figure below.[image: Representation of the problem in hand]

My question will be what is the probability of having these two lines (the one at the origin and the random one). My first idea is to take $\theta_1,\theta_2$ from a uniform distribution and so I'll just need to find the condition for the crossing and I can then just integrate $\int\int d\theta_1 d\theta_2$ and this will be some function of $d/R$. Starting from this I could write that for this crossing to happen we should have $-d<y(0)<d$ where $y(x)$ is the line equation for the random line. I can then rewrite this condition as: $|\cos(\theta_1) \cot(\frac{\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2}) + \sin(\theta_1) |\leq \frac{d}{R}$.

Numerically, I can find this probability (I did two things, first I would take a large amount of random line about 10 million and see how many cross on average and change $d/R$ and see how it changes and the other was just to check with the condition above for all values of $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in [0,2\pi]$ and also average and both methods gives the same results). But I'm trying to find an analytical expression and I'm stuck here. My idea is to first fix $\theta_1$ then find a condition for $\theta_2$ and then integrate $\theta_2$ and afterwards integrate $\theta_1$ between $0,2\pi$ and this should in principle give me the probability, but I can't seem to find a way to express the integration condition for $\theta_2$, I tried doing it with Mathematica as well but it's not working out. Any help will be appreciated.

Also, if needed, here's the results that I got from numerics for the probability.

[image: Probability of crossing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer.

Let me first fix an arbitrary point $A$ on the circle. Let the two endpoints of the vertical segment be called $P$ (for $y=d$) and $Q$ (for $y=-d$). Extending the lines $AP$ and $AQ$ until they intersect the circle again I obtain the points $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively. Note that for an arbitrary point $B$ on the circle, the line $AB$ will intersect $PQ$ if and only if $B$ is on the small arc $A_1 A_2$. Let me also denote the center of the circle by $O$.

We first assume that $0\leq \theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the argument of the point $A$, i.e., that $A$ is in the first quadrant.

Now time for some geometry. Let me denote the angle $\widehat{PAO}$ by $\alpha$ and the angle $\widehat{QAO}$ by $\beta$ and $\phi:=\alpha+\beta$ will be the measure of the angle $\widehat{PAQ}$. Note that the triangle $\triangle A_1 OA$ is isosceles, so $\mu(\widehat{OA_1 A})=\alpha$. Similarly $\mu(\widehat{OA_2 A})=\beta$. By summing up the angles around the origin, it follows that $\mu(\widehat{A_1 OA_2})=2(\alpha+\beta)=2\phi$.

We are left to understand the function $\phi(\theta)$. We can restrict to the case $R=1$ by simultaneously scaling down $d:=\frac{d}{R}$. Consider the triangle $\triangle PAQ$. Clearly
\begin{equation*}
AP=\sqrt{cos^2(\theta)+(sin(\theta)-d)^2}=\sqrt{1+d^2-2dsin(\theta)}
\end{equation*}
and similarly
\begin{equation*}
AQ=\sqrt{1+d^2+2dsin(\theta)}.
\end{equation*}

Applying the cosine law in $\triangle PAQ$ we get $4d^2=2+2d^2-2\sqrt{(1+d^2)^2-4d^2sin^2(\theta)}cos(\phi)$ which after simplification implies
\begin{equation*}
\phi(\theta)=arccos\Big( \frac{1-d^2}{\sqrt{(1+d^2)^2-4d^2 sin^2(\theta)}} \Big),
\end{equation*}
assuming my computations are correct. Note that since $d\leq 1$, $0\leq\mu(\phi)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, so we are in the bijective domain of $cos$.

So, given a point $A(\theta)$ in the first quadrant, the probability of choosing $B$ such that $AB$ intersects $PQ$ will be $\frac{\mu(\widehat{A_1 O A_2})}{2\pi}=\frac{\phi(\theta)}{\pi}$. Note that by symmetry, we have the same probability whenever $A$ is in any of the other quadrants as well. Therefore the requested probability should be
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \phi(\theta) d\theta.
\end{equation*}

I am not sure how easy it is to integrate this off the top of my head, but at least numerical methods should work for the relatively simple dependency.

Comment: (+1) If divided by another $2\pi$, this agrees with your plot when I do the integration numerically.

Comment: Oh thank you. I thought I missed something with the scaling. Will correct.

Comment: With $R=1,$ let $l(\theta)$ be the length of arc $A_1A_2.$  You've shown $l(\theta)=2\phi(\theta),$ so the required probability is $\mathbb E\left(l(\theta)\over 2\pi \right)={1\over 2\pi}{1\over \pi/2}\int_0^{\pi\over 2}l(\theta)d\theta={1\over 2\pi}{1\over \pi/2}\int_0^{\pi\over 2}2\phi(\theta)d\theta={2\over\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi\over 2}\phi(\theta)d\theta,$ which agrees numerically with your plot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and detailed answer!